# How do I find out the big O notation of each of these algorithms?

Tags: algorithm, big-o

I've been set a problem where I have a series of questions relating to these two algorithms, however I'm struggling to understand the concept of the big O notation which I feel like is very simple.

Essentially I need to find out what the big O notation is, how long it will take for each algorithm to a solve a problem of one and two million operations.

Algorithm A:

```
SET sum TO 0
FOR i=1 to size
   FOR j=1 to 10000
   sum=sum+1
```

Algorithm B:

```
SET sum TO 0
FOR i=1 to size
    FOR j=1 to size
    sum = sum + 1
```

This is supposing the computer can perform one million operations per second

Comment: "Essentially I need to find out what the big O notation is" -> please use Google with something like "big O notation explained". If neccessary, come back with a specific question about the bit you do not understand / a failed attempt at analysis of some code sample.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with the last phrase of your post: the time complexity of an algorithm is not dependent on the number of operations a computer can perform per second. It is irrelevant.

I assume the `sum = sum + 1` statement belongs *inside* the inner `FOR` loop -- the indentation does not make this clear.

Both algorithms execute `sum = sum + 1` several times. We may consider that one execution of `sum = sum + 1` takes constant time.

Now, the difference between the two algorithms is the number of times the inner loop runs. In the first version, that is a *constant* (10000). This means that one execution of the complete `FOR` loop will take constant time. It does not depend on *size*.

This means the first algorithm has only one loop that depends on *size*: it executes the inner loop *size* times. And so the time complexity is *O(size)*.

In the second version however, the inner loop *also* runs *size* times. So there it clearly depends on *size*. The number of times that the inner most statement is executed is now *size<sup>2</sup>*. So the time complexity is *O(size<sup>2</sup>)*.